# abstract appears in mactex but not in texlive for achemso package

Tags: texlive, mactex, abstract, achemso

For preparation of a communication for an ACS journal I am using the achemso package and the following header

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=communication]{achemso}
```

Then, after defining the authors, I write my document starting with

```
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
 Here goes my abstract...
\end{abstract}
```

Surprisingly, when I compile this document with pdflatex in different machines I get different behaviour. When compiling with MacTex, I find that the abstract is properly formatted with the sans-serif fonts required by ACS. When I compile with texlive the abstract is shown as single column in the last page of the document, after the main text, acknowledgements and references.

If I include the \listfiles command in my input, I get different results for both distributions. This is the difference between the output of the two, after doing "diff right.tex wrong.tex"

```
1c1
< achemso.cls    2012/05/08 v3.7a Submission to ACS journals
---
> achemso.cls    2009/09/01 v3.3a Submission to ACS journals
9,16c9,15
< geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
< ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
< ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
< ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
< helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)
< caption.sty    2012/02/19 v3.2f Customizing captions (AR)
< caption3.sty    2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
< courier.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)
---
> geometry.sty    2008/12/21 v4.2 Page Geometry
> ifpdf.sty    2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
> ifvtex.sty    2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
> helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)
> caption.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k Customizing captions (AR)
> caption3.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k caption3 kernel (AR)
> courier.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)
21,26c20,23
< graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
< pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
< infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
< ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
< mathptmx.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS)
< setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
---
> graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
> pdftex.def    2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
> mathptmx.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS)
> setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
28,30c25,28
< jacsat.cfg    2012/05/08 v3.7a achemso configuration: J. Am. Chem. Soc.
< natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
< natmove.sty    2010/01/15 v1.1a Automatic citation moving with natbib
---
> varioref.sty    2009/09/13 v1.4w package for extended references (FMi)
> jacsat.cfg    2009/09/01 v3.3a achemso configuration: J. Am. Chem. Soc.
> natbib.sty    2009/07/16 8.31 (PWD, AO)
> natmove.sty    2009/04/20 v1.1 Automatic citation moving with natbib
33,41d30
< pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
< ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
< epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
< grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
< kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
< kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 < kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
< etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
< epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: Of course, the same achemso package files were used in both cases.

Comment: We will need more details here: add `\listfiles` to your input and edit in the resulting file lists, please.

Comment: Updated with \listfiles output.

Comment: In the document that does work which lines in the \listfiles output are different?

Comment: I suspect that the machine where the thing doesn't work has an outdated TeX distribution; probably a TeX Live/Debian 2009. The only way out is to upgrade it.

Comment: You've got something up with your `achemso` installation: while you've got the same main file in both cases, the config file (`jacsat.cfg`) differs in version. That may be the issue: I'd try fixing that before anything else.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to an outdated TeX distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all. The problem was all sorted updating the texlive distribution using

sudo apt-get install texlive-full